# How to compare and display the new prop after receiving it in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to receive new props into `Pictures` component from `searchBarItems` component and set the state in `searchBarItems` component so I can map through and display the new props.

So far the `Pictures` component has been able to receive the props from parent when a search is submitted. After that I'm unable to compare the previous props and next state in `static getDerivedStateFromProps` within `Pictures` component. It gives an error saying `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.   I tried using `componentWillReceiveProps` and it gives me error `Cannot read property 'map' of null`.

How do I compare the difference in props and set a new state in `defaultImages` so I can map through?

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      enteredData: null
    }
  }


  enteredDatahandler = (ctp) => {
    this.setState({enteredData: ctp })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <SearchBarItems ctpEnteredData={this.enteredDatahandler}/>
          <Pictures ptcEnteredData={this.state.enteredData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

pictures.js

```
class Pictures extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    // console.log(props)
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      defaultImages: []
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    unsplash.search.collections("row", 3, 60)
    .then(toJson)
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({ defaultImages:json.results });
    });
  }


  //*********** Receive new Props ***********
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {

    console.log(nextProps.ptcEnteredData); //success
    console.log(prevState.defaultImages); //success
    // if(nextProps.ptcEnteredData !== prevState.defaultImages ) {
    //   this.setState({ defaultImages:nextProps.ptcEnteredData }) 

    //commented out code above gives an error that says Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined 

    // return {defaultImages: nextProps.ptcEnteredData}; //Cannot read property 'map' of null
     // }
    }






  // componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  //     this.setState({ defaultImages:nextProps.ptcEnteredData });
  //   } //Cannot read property 'map' of null
 //*****************************************


  render() {
    const pictures = this.state.defaultImages;
    const listItemsPictures = pictures.map((picture, index) =>
      picture.preview_photos.map((picobj,i)=> {
        return (
          <Picture key={picobj.id} pictureobj={picobj}/>
        )
      })
    )


    return (
      <div>
          {listItemsPictures}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Pictures
```

SearchBarItems.js:

```
class SearchBarItems extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchImagebox: '',
      searchImageData: null
     }
  }



  enterKeyHandler = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter'){
    event.preventDefault();
       unsplash.search.collections(this.search.value, 1, 60)
        .then(toJson)
        .then(json => {
            this.props.ctpEnteredData(json.results);            
      });
     }
   }


 render() {
   return (
     <div>
        <form autoComplete="off">
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="search" 
          placeholder="Search.." 
          ref={input => this.search = input}
          onKeyPress={this.enterKeyHandler}/>
        </form>
    </div>  
    )
  }
}



export default SearchBarItems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) it is not recommended to use componentWillReceiveProps
2. If you are going to put state update in "**componentWillReceiveProps**" or "**componentDidUpdate**" most likely you are doing something wrong or misunderstood state/props workflow.
3. Solution:

   ```
   render() {
           const pictures = this.props.ptcEnteredData || this.state.defaultImages;
           const listItemsPictures = pictures.map((picture, index) =>
           ...
   ```

If you have **ptcEnteredData** from parent component(**props**) than use it, otherwise use defaultImages.
You don't need **componentWillReceiveProps** method at all.